# why setInterval() does not repeat my function?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, setinterval

I was trying to do a chrome extension in which a function is to be repeated after a specific time.The flow goes like this,button press(popup.html)->execute(popup.js)->triggers(cont.js)->reload page for every 3 seconds.

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    Event (or) movie name:<input type="text" name="inp" id="inp1"><br>
    <button id="set">Set Reminder</button>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

popup.js

```
document.getElementById("set").addEventListener("click", function () {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, { file: 'cont.js' });
    });
});
```

cont.js

```
setInterval(function () {
    location.reload(true);
}, 3000);
```

The page reload happens only once but according to setInterval() function, it should happen for every 3 seconds. help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: SETINTERVAL is only a javascript function.. And in this case you are trying to excuting seperate files. By the way please show up you try (Code).

Comment: yea, i have updated the code. check it out.

Comment: Please make it clear that why u want to excute all three seperate files rather than creating one file and split them into functions.

Comment: There is a situation where i need to access a different Dom other than the popup.html which is not mentioned in the code. That's why i have used different files.

Comment: Just guessing - perhaps the `setInterval` is present on the initial page, and the reload of the page erases the instance of the timer?

Comment: instead of reloading the page. i have tried to put a alert(). But it too works only once.

Comment: Can we see your manifest.json?

Answer (score 0):

In a Chrome extension, the *popup script* is executed **only** while the popup page is opened and active. When your `cont.js` runs, it reloads the tab and the *popup page* becomes inactive, since the tab is reloaded it won't have the `cont.js` script in it, and since the popup page is inactive the `popup.js` script doesn't run, hence it won't inject `cont.js` again and the tab won't reload every 3 seconds as supposed to. For this, create a *persistent background script*, this type of extension script is always running. Here's a [tutorial](https://dev.to/michaeldscherr/building-a-simple-chrome-extension-1mal#targetText=Background%20Scripts&targetText=Extensions%20are%20event%20based%20programs,then%20react%20with%20specified%20instructions.) for a simple extension that shows you how to use background scripts.

Comment: i tried executing it in background.js but still the same. :(

Comment: @Balajis It should work, unless there's some error in your code. Be kind as to show me the code of your manifest file, and your background script file. Edit your question and include those, so that I can help you fix it. What you're trying to do is easy, don't panic, it will be solved.